# Run docker-compose command from C# .Net 4.7

Tags: c#, .net, runspace

I'm wishing to run a command from C# to a container set up via docker-compose. In Powershell, I run this command and the file is created:

```
docker-compose exec database sh -c "mysqldump -u((username)) -p((password)) ((databasename)) > /backups/test.sql"
```

When I run the following code it seems to ignore the environment variables, even though I have them set. It only creates a file named `backup.sql` and the SQL outputted to the file indicates that no database was selected. I've verified the env variables are set by outputting the last parameters string to the console.

```
var exportPath = $"/backups/backup.sql {DateTime.Now}"; 
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();
    runspace.SessionStateProxy.Path.SetLocation(Path.GetFullPath(".."));
    using (var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {

        var cmd = new Command("docker-compose");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("exec");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("database");
        cmd.Parameters.Add($"sh -c \"mysqldump - u{GetEnv("MYSQL_USERNAME")} " +
            $"-p{GetEnv("MYSQL_PASSWORD")} {GetEnv("MYSQL_DATABASE")} > {exportPath} \"");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
        pipeline.Invoke();
    }
}
```

`GetEnv` is just a convenience method for `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`

I'm fairly certain that I am not setting the parameters right, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Where are the environment variables set? In the container? On the host machine?

Comment: The program uses DotNetEnv to load them from a file.

Comment: "GetEnv is just a convenience method for Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable" - now you say a file - which is it?

Comment: DotNetEnv sets the environment variables from values in the file. See here: https://github.com/tonerdo/dotnet-env

Comment: Anyway, that part is working just fine - as noted in the original question.

Comment: At a guess the issue is the space between - and u

Comment: @John Fixed that. For some reason copy+paste from the command put those in everywhere. Still having the same issue.

Comment: @eltiare Ignore me. I misread your code.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up and used CliWrap because it is easier to debug. I couldn't figure out how to set the current directory, but fortunately I could modify the rest of the program to look for stuff in the current directory.

```
using CliWrap;
using CliWrap.Buffered;

var now = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "-");
var exportPath = $"/backups/backup.sql-{now}";

var cmd = $"exec -T database sh -c \"mysqldump -u{GetEnv("MYSQL_USER")} " +
          $"-p{GetEnv("MYSQL_PASSWORD")} {GetEnv("MYSQL_DATABASE")} > {exportPath}\"";

Console.WriteLine(cmd);

var result = await Cli.Wrap("docker-compose")
    .WithArguments(cmd)
    .ExecuteBufferedAsync();

Console.WriteLine(result.StandardOutput);
Console.WriteLine(result.StandardError);
```

The library can be found here: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap

Answer (score 2):

I came across to [FluentDocker](https://github.com/mariotoffia/FluentDocker) which seems like a nice way to run `docker-compose` from c#.

Here is an example from the project page:

```cs
using (
        var container =
          new Builder().UseContainer()
            .UseImage("kiasaki/alpine-postgres")
            .ExposePort(5432)
            .WithEnvironment("POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword")
            .WaitForPort("5432/tcp", 30000 /*30s*/)
            .Build()
            .Start())
      {
        var config = container.GetConfiguration(true);
        Assert.AreEqual(ServiceRunningState.Running, config.State.ToServiceState());
      }
```

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the project in any way nor have attempted to use it yet.